# How to fix java.io.FileNotFoundException: Response: '404: Not Found' for url: 'http://localhost:7001/Socket-war/Servlet'

Tags: java, url, filenotfoundexception, inputstreamreader, buffered

I am using the code below to invoke a servlet from my Java class :

```
  URL url = new URL( "http://localhost:7001/Socket-war/Servlet" );
  new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(url.openStream()));
```

Getting an Exception:

```
java.io.FileNotFoundException: Response: '404: Not Found' for url: 'http://localhost:7001/Socket-war/Servlet'
```

Everything is fine; I have used it before as well in my other Program; but now raising exception...

Somebody tell me WHY ???  Any advice or suggestion would be highly appreciable.

Thank you!!!

Comment: Can you reach the servlet from your browser?

Comment: Yes, using Browser I can.

Comment: can you try 127.0.0.1 instead of localhost?

Comment: Also, are there any proxy setup in your network?

Comment: Getting Exception again:                                               java.io.FileNotFoundException: Response: '404: Not Found' for url: 'http://127.0.0.1:7001/Socket-war/Servlet'
 at weblogic.net.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream(HttpURLConnection.java:568) at weblogic.net.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream(HttpURLConnection.java:568)
 at weblogic.net.http.SOAPHttpURLConnection.getInputStream(SOAPHttpURLConnection.java:37)
 at java.net.URL.openStream(URL.java:1037)

Comment: you didnot put http:// before 127... ?

Comment: Yes there is Proxy setup

Comment: Exception:    


java.io.FileNotFoundException: Response: '404: Not Found' for url: 'http://127.0.0.1:7001/Socket-war/Servlet'
 at weblogic.net.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream(HttpURLConnection.java:568) at weblogic.net.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream(HttpURLConnection.java:568)
 at weblogic.net.http.SOAPHttpURLConnection.getInputStream(SOAPHttpURLConnection.java:37)
 at java.net.URL.openStream(URL.java:1037)

Comment: Proxy shouldn't affect the localhost servlet connection. Can you provide a sample servlet and how you are connecting it? We would like to run that in our machine

Comment: Its a simple Servlet Sir with Hello World Code; I need to invoke it as a part of a complete Processing cycle of my Project; can't provide the whole code but it is as simple as it sounds...

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/52071/discussion-between-hirak-and-user3462765)

Comment: But, yes My Project cycle starts  with a Java class which is serving as a JMS Message Producer in which I set some Initial Context Parameters by using code:    Hashtable ht = new Hashtable();
  ht.put(Context.INITIAL_CONTEXT_FACTORY,"weblogic.jndi.WLInitialContextFactory");
  ht.put(Context.PROVIDER_URL, "t3://localhost:7001");
 
    ctx = new InitialContext(ht);

::::::::::: May be this has got some issue ???

Answer (score 0):

This answer is in response to the chat happened.

Following is my servlet code

```
protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
          response.getWriter().println("Hello World");
            response.getWriter().flush();
            response.getWriter().close();
    }
```

Following is my connection code, and it works.

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    System.setProperty("http.proxyHost", "proxy.***.com");
    System.setProperty("http.proxyPort", "####");
     Authenticator authenticator = new Authenticator() {
                    public PasswordAuthentication getPasswordAuthentication() {
                        return (new PasswordAuthentication("user",
                                "pwd".toCharArray()));
                    }
                };
    Authenticator.setDefault(authenticator);
     URL url = new URL( "http://localhost:8080/ImageCanvas/Servlet2" );
     BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(url.openStream()));
     String line;
     while((line=br.readLine())!= null){
         System.out.println(line);
         System.out.flush();
     }
     br.close();

}
```

Comment: Yes I am trying to do the same but, yes My Project cycle starts with a Java class which is serving as a JMS Message Producer in which I set some Initial Context Parameters by using code: Hashtable ht = new Hashtable(); ht.put(Context.INITIAL_CONTEXT_FACTORY,"weblogic.jndi.WLInitialContextFactory"); ht.put(Context.PROVIDER_URL, "t3://localhost:7001"); ctx = new InitialContext(ht); ::::::::::: May be this has got some issue ???